# How to get more params when I use the rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to get more params when I use the rest framework ?

This is my model:

```
class CloudServer(models.Model):
    buytime = models.ForeignKey(to=BuyTime)  # time duration
    expiration_time = models.DateTimeField()  # expire time
    availablearea = models.ForeignKey(to=AvailableArea)
    profile = models.TextField()  # profile
```

This is my serializers:

```
class CloudServerCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CloudServer
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is my views:

```
class CloudServerCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CloudServerCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = CloudServer.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # there I want more params.
        #serializer.save()
        return Response(data="Create success", status=HTTP_200_OK, exception=None)
```

The rest framework api web browser:

[image]

You see, there are only 4 params related to the model fields.

In there I want to get more params inputs here(such as 10 count), 
and when I create I want to save 4 of the 10 params to the model serializer, and the remainder 6 params to use as other usefulness in `CloudServerCreateAPIView`'s `post` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at  [serializer fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializer-fields) :

You can put more serializer fields in your `CloudServerCreateSerializer` :

```
class CloudServerCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...
    ext_one = serializers.CharField()
    ext_two = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CloudServer
        fields = "__all__"
```